# Mudança dinâmica da tag meta viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-meta-tag

É possível alterar o *viewport* de uma página e ter imediato efeito sem ter que atualizá-la?

Supondo que tenho o seguinte *viewport* na página para exibição em dispositivos móveis (smartphones e tablets):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

Então, eu tenho um botão no final da página, do tipo <kbd>Versão completa</kbd> que, ao ser clicado, chama uma função JavaScript (ou jQuery) que altera o `width` do *viewport* para 1024 pixels de largura. Essa alteração na propriedade do `<meta>`, via script, já altera a visualização da página de imediato ou precisa fazer um *reload*?

Outra coisa: o *viewport* com largura definida em pixels, deve conter `px` ou apenas o número (ex., `width=1024,` ou `width=1024px,`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta resposta aplica-se à dispositivos móveis.

Percebi que ao mudar dinamicamente o `viewport` para uma largura fixa, a resolução da tela muda, porém o conteúdo não se adapta à largura.

Imagem com `viewport="device-width..."`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Resultado após clicar no botão <kbd>Versão completa</kbd>:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**No entanto,** o contrário funciona perfeitamente, ou seja, alterar o `viewport` de valor fixo (`width=1024`) para modo de dispositivos móveis (`width=device-width...`).

**Conclusão:**

É necessário atualizar a página para que o conteúdo da página se ajuste ao `viewport`. Neste caso, seria necessário guardar o novo valor do `viewport` em uma variável (ex., SESSION, localStorage...) e atualizar a página e renderizar com o novo `viewport`.

**Exemplo usando `SESSION` com PHP:**

```
<?php
if( $_SESSION['viewport'] == "desktop"){
?>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1024...
<?php
}else{
?>
<meta name="viewport" content="device-width...
<?php
}
?>
```

**Exemplo usando `localStorage` do JavaScript:**

```
<script>
if( localStorage.viewport == "desktop"){
   document.write('<meta name="viewport" content="width=1024...');
}else{
   document.write('<meta name="viewport" content="device-width...');
}
</script>
```

> Ao definir um valor `width` no *viewport*, não se deve usar `px`
>   (conforme exemplos acima).